# Magento - migrating orders from 1.4 to 1.7 manually from DB

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

Ok I’m in trouble, I viewed dozens of topics on stackoverflow and magento forum and still have no solution.
What happened is we were migrating Magento 1.4.2 to the latest 1.7. We made a backup of everything, we did upgrade overnight and everything was almost perfect.
1,5 days later someone notices that one plugin is not working - it’s not only not working but charging people wrong price! Biig trouble. So we try to fix it but it’s a nightmare, it’s the middle of the day and quick decision - bring back the backup. We again backup current 1.7 DB and swap systems to 1.4.2.
The backup is there live, we’re working in the background, we fix it and 2 days later put 1.7 happily live without any troubles.

Here’s the trick! For 2 days orders landed in backup 1.4.2 DB. Now we have 1.7 and about 100 orders are missing.
Now we tried millions of solutions out there but they’re all about migrating all DB. The trick is that we have over 10k orders and need to transfer only about 100 (with connected users of course).

Any clues? Any ideas? I found something about SOAP API but not sure how to deal with that.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SOAP api.
Create a script as this:

```
 $client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');


 $session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

 $filters = array(
      'created_at' => array('gt'=>'2013-05-15 12:00:00')
 );
 $result = $client->call($session, 'order.list');
 var_dump ($result);
```

That gives you the orders. Then you can create a script to insert them in the new db or manually purchase them again i don't know which one is easiest.

I hope this was helpful, otherwise drop a comment.